# How to tag(base tag) a git repository(full repo) which has previous commits and tags?

Tags: java, git, jgit

I am trying to add a base tag for my project(i.e repository) which has lot of previous commits and  tags using the following code:

```
Git git = Git.open(new File("local path"));
TagCommand tagcmd = git.tag().setName(tagName).setMessage(message)
Ref ref = tagcmd.call();
SshSessionFactory.setInstance(new JschConfigSessionFactory() {

    @Override
    protected void configure(Host host, Session session) {
        session.setPassword(remotePassword);
    }
});

PushCommand cmd = git.push().add(ref);
cmd.call();
```

When the above code runs the tag is added to the last commit and does not reflect in all the files. i want this tag to be in all my files in the repository.

How to tag (base tag) for my existing repo which has previous commits and tags?

Comment: In Git, you cannot tag files, only commits can be tagged. Commit all changes before you create a tag. What relevance has the PushCommand in the code snippet w.r.t the question?

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann sorry, updated the code.. kindly check... can i do a dummy commit in the git and add tag for that reference? does it work??

Comment: Please make sure you have a good understanding what Git tag really are. In doubt read something like this: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging